# Passwordless ssh on archlinux (after ssh-copy-id still prompts for password)

Tags: ssh, arch-linux

On ubuntu/mint, all I need to do for passwordless ssh login is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa # on both pc
ssh-copy-id targetpc
ssh targetpc # does not prompt from password anymore
```

and that's all..

I do the same on archlinux (or manjaro), it's not working on the third step, it still prompts for password..

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/blablabla/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.11.3 [192.168.11.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/blablabla/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/blablabla/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blablabla/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/blablabla/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blablabla/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: identity file /home/blablabla/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client arcfour hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server arcfour hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 71:d2:05:dd:21:d1:ae:fc:a8:e5:f2:1c:2c:60:31:85
debug1: Host '192.168.11.3' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/blablabla/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/blablabla/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/blablabla/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/blablabla/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

and when using old home directory (from ubuntu), the ssh-copy-id shows some information that i've never seen before

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
```

is there some steps missing that i should do on archlinux?

EDIT: the version of openssh is differ on both machine, one is 6.1p1-6, others was 6.2p1-1

Comment: Is Arch the client or the server? I guess the client.

Comment: both are now using archlinux

Comment: Then check if the server side actually have the key, and allowed to login, it's not root right?

Comment: yup, it's not root, both have the key id_[r|d|ecd]sa and id_[r|d|ecd]sa.pub in .ssh folder with correct permisson

Comment: and i have tried to rm .ssh/* on both, and then ssh-keygen, ssh-copy-id, but it still prompts for password

Comment: typically it means your home directory or .ssh/ directories do not have correct permissions.  check out the remote end's syslogs for errors from sshd.

Comment: no log on /var/log/syslog.log

Comment: also no meaningful ssh log on /var/log/[everything|errors].log

Comment: ah it works, chmod 700 ~ @jsbillings please add an answer (/var/log/auth.log --> sshd : Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/blablabla), i will vote for it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically it means your home directory or .ssh/ directories do not have correct permissions. check out the remote end's syslogs for errors from sshd.

for example, a line containing:

```
sshd[pid]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/yourusername
```

on

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

means you must do

```
chmod 700 ~
```